# Did Hillary Clinton admit in her memoirs to creating ISIS?

Tags: united-states, quotes, isis, hillary-clinton

The Iranian religious leader Ayatollah Khamenei [claimed in a speech](http://english.khamenei.ir/news/2103/Leader-s-speech-in-meeting-with-government-officials-and-ambassadors) posted on his official website that:

> Some Americans have confessed in their own memoirs [including Hillary
>   Clinton's memoirs] that they have played a role in creating,
>   developing and establishing DAESH and today too, they are supporting
>   them.

Did Hillary Clinton ever write anything on her memoirs that "confessed" to playing a role in the formation of ISIS/Daesh?

This question is distinct from [the question which in some ways inspired this one](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/31521), as it is regarding the specific verification of a claim made about Hillary Clinton's memoirs, and may or may not be true independent of whether the American government sponsored the formation of ISIS.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate, since this is a far more specific question.

Comment: You're asking the same question, in fact you're using the same source for your queried claim as the second reference in the linked question. This particular answer addresses the explains this misunderstanding. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/31545/28608

Comment: @GeoffAtkins I used the same source, because I became intrigued about one of its other claims while reading it. The answer you linked to has no link whatsoever to this question.

Comment: Please improve the target question instead of adding a new one which is extremely similar.

Comment: I really don't see how this is a duplicate. The claim here is that Clinton [and others] admitted in her memoirs to "have played a role" in the growth of ISIS, while the linked claim is absolute: "[ISIS] were created with the purpose of...".It's possible for the two questions to have different answers, and an answer to one doesn't answer the other. There's no reason for an answer to "Is ISIS made by the USA?" to discuss Hillary Clinton's memoirs, even if there was a partial admission like "Mistakes were made which contributed to..."

Comment: I'm reopening this because it is a separate question about a rumor about Hillary's memoirs, but obviously I'd want to add it to my answer about various claims that the US takes responsibility for ISIS.

Comment: There is a distinct difference between the US government being responsible for the created of Daesh (through their actions in the Middle East, particularly Iraq) and the US actually sponsoring them with funds and/or weapons.

Comment: If this is a question solely about the content of her memoirs (I assume this means HARD CHOICES?), then it should be very easy to verify or not.  Just go to a bookstore and look at the index (if there is one).

Answer (score 7):

[Speech on Khamenei Website: Hillary Clinton ‘Confessed’ That US Created ISIS](http://www.cnsnews.com/news/article/patrick-goodenough/speech-khamenei-website-hillary-clinton-confessed-us-created-isis)

> A year ago, claims began circulating in Egypt and elsewhere in a
> region notorious for conspiracy theories that Hillary Clinton, in her
> published memoir, acknowledged that the U.S. had created ISIS.
>
> The “excerpts” – which appear nowhere in the book – said the U.S.
> decided to set up ISIS in response to the Egyptian military’s
> game-changing ousting of Mohammed Morsi’s Muslim Brotherhood
> administration in mid-2013.
>
> The idea was to replace autocratic leaders in the Middle East with
> Islamists whom the U.S. would apparently have more success in
> directing than the current regimes. The customary allegations about a
> U.S. desire to control the region’s oil supplies were cited.
>
> One Egyptian blogger wrote later that the fake excerpts had first
> emerged on Facebook pages associated with pro-Egyptian military
> sentiment. Many supporters of the military’s toppling of Morsi accused
> the U.S. government of backing the Muslim Brotherhood.

[Egyptian And Lebanese Media Claim Hillary Clinton Admits To Creating ISIS](https://www.buzzfeed.com/miriamberger/hillary-clinton-admitted-to-creating-isis-in-her-memoirs-or?utm_term=.pqjXOE288#.qs032aldd)

> The accusations prompted the U.S. Embassy in Lebanon to take to
> Facebook and Twitter and formally deny the claim on Aug. 6.
>
> “Any
> suggestion that the United States ever considered recognizing ISIS as
> anything other than a terrorist organization, or had any role in its
> creation, is patently false. Allegations circulating in Lebanon to the
> contrary are fabricated.”

Answer (score 3):

This is not a complete answer.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dqn0bm4E9yw) is probably the most relevant information regarding the claim. In this video, Clinton claims that the US has indeed acted in the 1980s/1990s in the Pakistan and nearby areas. She claims that these actions have indeed in some ways, led to the creation/power of certain terrorist organizations.

I believe that this talks more about Al Qaeda rather than ISIS.

Another partly relevant statement may be the one made by Donald Trump, that [Obama and Hilary literally founded ISIS](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/statements/2016/aug/11/donald-trump/donald-trump-pants-fire-claim-obama-founded-isis-c/). This was judged to be a "Pants-on-fire" lie.

Unfortunately, I have not read the her memoirs. However, Hilary have indeed "confessed" that the US have supported people that became terrorist today. However, I was unable to find anything explicitly referencing ISIS or DAESH. And of course, I'm almost certain that nowhere did Hilary state, except maybe as a joke, that she outright founded ISIS.